# How to submit multiple combobox in a form and check using javascript(Quiz application)?

Tags: php, javascript, html

i try to make quiz/exam application. I have no problem with creating single choice question(My reference is from http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut180.shtml), but i still confused how to make multiple choice choice question.
For single choice i can simply use radio button:

```
  <form method="POST" name="myquiz">
  <div class="qheader">
  9) What's the world's most widely spoken language?</div>
  <div class="qselections">
  <input type="radio" value="a" name="question9">a) English<br>
  <input type="radio" value="b" name="question9">b) Spanish<br>
  <input type="radio" value="c" name="question9">c) Mandarin<br>
  <input type="radio" value="d" name="question9">d) French<br>
  </div>
  </form>
```

For scoring, they use javascript:

```
//Enter total number of questions:
var totalquestions=10

//Enter the solutions corresponding to each question:
var correctchoices=new Array()
correctchoices[1]='a' //question 1 solution
correctchoices[2]='a' //question 2 solution, and so on.
correctchoices[3]='c'
correctchoices[4]='c'
correctchoices[5]='c'
correctchoices[6]='c'
correctchoices[7]='b'
correctchoices[8]='b'
correctchoices[9]='c'
correctchoices[10]='b'

/////Don't edit beyond here//////////////////////////

function gradeit(){
var incorrect=null
for (q=1;q<=totalquestions;q++){
    var thequestion=eval("document.myquiz.question"+q)
    for (c=0;c<thequestion.length;c++){
        if (thequestion[c].checked==true)
        actualchoices[q]=thequestion[c].value
        }
```

etc...

The problem is when i try to make multiple choice question, i tried use this one but still failed:

```
<div class="qheader">
1) What is the difference between a jungle and a rain forest?</div>
<div class="qselections">
<input type="checkbox" value="a" name="question1">a) No difference. Simply two different ways in referring to the same thing.<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="b" name="question1">b) A jungle in general receives less rain than a rain forest.<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="c" name="question1">c) A jungle refers to the thickest area of a rain forest<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="d" name="question1">d) A jungle and a rain forest each contain their own group of distinct plants and animals.<br>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="qheader">
    1) What is the difference between a jungle and a rain forest?</div>
    <div class="qselections">
    <input type="checkbox" value="a" name="question1[]">a) No difference. Simply two different ways in referring to the same thing.<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="b" name="question1[]">b) A jungle in general receives less rain than a rain forest.<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="c" name="question1[]">c) A jungle refers to the thickest area of a rain forest<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="d" name="question1[]">d) A jungle and a rain forest each contain their own group of distinct plants and animals.<br>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where are you facing the problem? I prefer you use the second type. This way you will receive the data in array and you can then simply use it according to your choice. You can fetch it this way: $question1 = empty($_POST['question1']) ? NULL : $_POST['question1']; it will give you an array if the user selects options, else it will set your variable to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `checkboxes names` like `question1,question2,question3,....`

```
<input type="checkbox" value="a" name="question1">a) No difference. Simply two different ways in referring to the same thing.<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="b" name="question2">b) A jungle in general receives less rain than a rain forest.<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="c" name="question3">c) A jungle refers to the thickest area of a rain forest<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="d" name="question4">d) A jungle and a rain forest each contain their own group of distinct plants and animals.<br>
```

Comment: i don't think so...if i gave name question2,question3,etc it will be considered as answer for question2,question3,etc